# Conditional distributions allowed pdf to take on single value?

Tags: probability, random-variables

My question is about Conditional probability distributions. From what I have learned, PDF's aren't allowed to take on singular values, yet I find that this definition seems to go out the window when we are talking conditional probability. Looking for some type of justification for this.

Why is it that when we are talking conditional, pdf's they are allowed to take on a single value.

I.E: For x and Y continuous:

$P[Y > y | X = x] =    \frac{f_x(x) \cap F_y[Y >y]}{f_x(x)}$

Why?

Comment: Because for a given value of $X$, $P(Y>y)$ is an area.

Comment: See the graph at the link. Every layer is a conditional distribution for a specific value of X. http://astarmathsandphysics.com/university-maths/probability-and-statistics/the-bivariate-normal-distribution-html-mad9d510.gif

Comment: Once the "horrendous mismash" in your post is cleansed, the answer is that $P(Y>y\mid X=x)$ is not defined pointwise as a function of $x$, in particular, yes, when $P(X=x)=0$, one can modify $P(Y>y\mid X=x)$ at some points $x$. Instead, what is rigorously defined is the random variable $P(Y>y\mid X)$, which, by definition, is $u(X)$ for some measurable $u$. Then one can use $P(Y>y\mid X=x)=u(x)$. Note that any other function $\bar u$ such that $P(u(X)=\bar u(X))=1$ could be used as well, which explains that $u(x)$ has no real meaning when $P(X=x)=0$, only the random variable $u(X)$ has.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for all your help! Every comment and answer is great! Really helped with my intuition. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is a horrendous mismash, but what you seem to mean is that is:$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y{>}y\mid X{=}x) ~=&~ \dfrac{\int_y^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,t)\operatorname d t}{f_X(x)} \\[1ex] =&~ \int_y^\infty f_{Y\mid X}(t\mid x)\operatorname d t\end{align}$$

This is okay.   We can handle *probability density functions* of continuous random variables in a mostly analogous manner to *probability mass functions* of discrete random variables.

For a given value, $x$, of random variable $X$, the (conditional) probability that random variable $Y$ exceeds a value, $y$, can be calculated if we know either both the joint probability density function and the marginal density function ( $f_{X,Y}, f_{X}$ ), *or* the conditional probability density function ( $f_{Y\mid X}$ ).

---

> From what I have learned, PDF's aren't allowed to take on singular values,

The probability that a continuous random variable will realise any *particular* value has zero measure (by definition).   This is not the same as saying it is impossible to do so; it is certain that the random variable will realise *some* value in the support.

Comment: This does not address the OP's query because joint PDFs and marginal PDFs are only defined up to negligible sets. In particular, the sentences "if we know either both **the** joint probability density function and **the** marginal density function (...) or **the** conditional probability density function" (my emphasis) are faulty.